# Origin of "another and a greater X"

Tags: phrase-origin, quotations, snowclones

Having recently happened across the fact that Greek ἄνωθεν *anothen* means "from above, higher," I'm now constantly when I see it thinking "another and a greater..." But where does *that* snowclone come from? It feels very King James Version, and indeed appears a lot in Christian contexts. ([Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=another+and+a+greater%2Ca+sadder+and+a+wiser&year_start=1600&year_end=1950).) Here are Google Books' oldest examples:

- [1635](https://books.google.com/books?id=KQLJqqW3UJgC&pg=RA2-PA110&dq=%22another+and+a+greater%22): "But if that be so, then thereupon riseth **another and a greater** doubt — namely, ..."
- [1620](https://books.google.com/books?id=4nSvFpvzrf4C&pg=PA94&dq=%22another+and+a+greater%22): "But to the end that we might not doubt of this favour, it is seconded with **another, and a greater**; For he sayth, *The Word of God, is made flesh.*"
- [1596](https://books.google.com/books?id=AEhnAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA29-IA1&dq=%22another+and+a+greater%22): "It may hap also, that the Corne being ripe ... may bee either burnt up, or mowed downe by the enemie ... or else from Heaven or other mishappe be set on fire, or which is **another, and a greater** mischiefe in the securest peace, in the greatest plentie of all thinges, yet are there Usurers, Monopolists ..."

Is this a literary reference? or if not, then why did it become such a popular and widespread set phrase?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a set phrase, it's just two concepts that often go toether.

Comment: Note that "another" was originally "an + other."

Comment: @alphabet Actually, it was originally "a nother". But it was frequently misparsed as "an other", so the word "nother" became "other".

Comment: Can you clarify that, please? Why are you equating 'from above, higher' with 'another and a greater..'?

Quite separately, how is there a snowclone here?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: "Higher" and "greater", especially in a KJV context, are basically synonyms. The [possible] snowclone is the phrase "another and a greater X", in that I still have the niggling feeling that there is an "original" X right on the tip of my tongue, to which the quoted instances of "another and a greater X" are consciously or unconsciously alluding. [But it's possible Barmar is right and there was no "original" after all.]

Comment: If they're basically synonyms then why are they worth Asking about, please? Still, how could a snowclone come into this - unless the fact of being a snowclone explained everything?

Comment: @Barmar Where might 'it was originally "a nother" ' come from, even if 
google.com/search?q=nother+etymology&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB1057GB1057&oq=nother+etymology&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i10i512l2j0i22i30j0i390i650l2.12078j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8' was wholly mistaken?